# Can SQL Server run over SCO SantaCruz Operations SO (Linux)?

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-linux

I wanna know if Microsoft SQL Server can run over the SO of Santa Cruz Operations SCO, Linux based SO, I already looked into the documentation available in it's web page but isn't specified, does anyone here knows if it's posible, due the fact than since the 2017 version MSSQL can run over linux, I just need to know if SCO is up to date for the support.

If you have already done the install, can you give some insights?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official platforms where you can install SQLServer: [sqlserver platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-2017#supportedplatforms)

In this case you can use Docker (
Develop once and run anywhere)